# Phusion Passenger Rails server - how to access from outside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, webrick

I switched from WEBrick to Phussion Passenger following this guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/PhusionRails/index.html.
I used PassengerPane to configure it.

Now I can access my app at ***myapp.local***,  instead of ***localhost:3000***

However, I don't know how to access it from the outside. It used to be ***ip:3000***

My vhost.conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.local
  DocumentRoot "/Users/martin/myapp/public"
  RackEnv development
  <Directory "/Users/martin/myapp/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: just access through your ip address....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ServerAlias YOURIP`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.local
  ServerAlias YOURIP
  DocumentRoot "/Users/martin/myapp/public"
  RackEnv development
  <Directory "/Users/martin/myapp/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can add as many aliases as you want (with real domain names for example).